# how to merge two dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add two dataframes but not getting the right result. I have two files in which one file is having column name and other file is having data. I want to merge them.

I am using '\001' delimiter.

Example:

df1:

```
56447MNEMILY 2703546.742893.9553218262930LP2018-11-21 09:18:46.040618
62872ILOPDYKE 1708138.269688.8052618165922LP2018-11-21 09:18:46.040618
04925MECARATUNK 2302545.231369.9861207221305LP2018-11-21 09:18:46.040618
```

df2:

```
meli_zip_cd_basemeli_stt_provncdmeli_city_nmmeli_typmeli_cntry_fipsmeli_latimeli_longimeli_area_cdmeli_fin_cdmeli_last_lnmeli_facmeli_msa_cdmeli_pmsa_cdmeli_dma_cdload_dt
```

Expected final result:

df_final:

```
meli_zip_cd_basemeli_stt_provncdmeli_city_nmmeli_typmeli_cntry_fipsmeli_latimeli_longimeli_area_cdmeli_fin_cdmeli_last_lnmeli_facmeli_msa_cdmeli_pmsa_cdmeli_dma_cdload_dt
56447MNEMILY 2703546.742893.9553218262930LP2018-11-21 09:18:46.040618
62872ILOPDYKE 1708138.269688.8052618165922LP2018-11-21 09:18:46.040618
04925MECARATUNK 2302545.231369.9861207221305LP2018-11-21 09:18:46.040618
```

Comment: Can you add to question what is `print (df1.head())` ? Because from sample data seems separator distingush problem

Comment: Could you please post expected output also

Comment: @RaviKulkarni Expected output is final_df.

Comment: So, `df2` has only _one_ line, and that line is the name of _one_ column?

Comment: @DYZ, yes df2 has only one line. That is column and df1 is having all the data. So i want to merge both the records.

Comment: And `df1` has _one_ column as well?

Comment: Also, it is not clear where you use `'\001'` and how is that relevant to your question. Please explain.

Comment: @DYZ records is separated by '\001' separator.

Comment: Which records? There are rows and columns in a DataFrame, none of them need to be separated.

Comment: @DYZ, forget about delimiter sir. Can you please tell me how to concat both dataframe in a single file. I want final_df as a output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the first (and only) row from `df2` to become the header of the first (and only) column in `df1`:

```
df1.columns = df2.iloc[0].values
```

Comment: getting error - IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: Judging by your own answer, `df2` does not have _any_ ries, contrary to what you told me

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the solution:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('/medaff/eureka/CDP/DMN_MELI_ZIP/DMN_MELI_ZIP.txt', delimiter='\001')
df2 = pd.read_csv('/medaff/eureka/CDP/HEADERS/DMN_MELI_ZIP_HEADER.txt', delimiter='\001')

df1.columns = df2.columns

df1.to_csv('/medaff/eureka/CDP/HEADERS/test.txt', sep ='\001', index=False)
```